# Dynamic SQL select multiple columns based on json field(s) without exposing SQL Injection risks

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, sql-injection, dynamic-sql

I'm creating a 'select colA, colB, colC, ...' stored proc, and I want the choice of columns to return to be based on JSON input.

The most basic way to achieve that is

```
DECLARE @jsonField nvarchar(max) = 'col1, col2, col3' --will get this from input json
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'Select '+@jsonField +'from tblFoo'
exec sys.sp_executesql @sql
```

But doing the above would create way too large a security hole for SQL Injection. The safe way that I can figure out is:

```
DECLARE @jsonUseField1 bit = 0
DECLARE @jsonUseField2 bit = 1--again would be getting this from json in the actual proc
--would also have to declare jsonField3, 4, 5, ...
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'Select idFieldName'
if(@jsonUseField1 = 1)
begin
    set @sql = @sql + ', field1Name'
end
if(@jsonUseField2 = 1)
begin
    set @sql = @sql + ', field2Name'
end
set @sql = @sql +'from tblFoo'
exec sys.sp_executesql @sql
```

The downside to the above method is that I'd have to add 5 extra lines to the proc per field I want to be queryable. This would make the stored proc long and hard to maintain. I'd also have to add a new field to the class that forms the json every time I want a new field.

Is there a way to achieve this behaviour without having to explicitly code out each queryable field, while still protecting against Injection? For example, is there a way to alter the first example to split the json field by a delimiter of some sort, and then rejoin after applying QUOTENAME() to each segment?

I'm using SQL Server 2019

I thought I'd share the solution I ended up running with incorporating Gareth's answer and Charlie's comment, and adding an explicit table reference (because I do joins and other things in the dynamic SQL) in case it is helpful to anyone.

```
DECLARE @ColumnNames NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
    (
        SELECT  STRING_AGG('tblFooTable.'+QUOTENAME(c.name), ',')
        FROM    sys.columns AS c
        WHERE   object_id =  OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.tblFooTable', 'U')
        AND  c.name IN (SELECT TRIM(value) FROM OPENJSON(@jsonData, '$.footblColumnNames'))
    );
DECLARE @sql2 nvarchar(max) = N'Select '+@ColumnNames
```

Comment: As far as I know, it is strongly recommended to use `String.Format("SELECT {0} FROM tblFoo", @jsonField)` instead of the + syntax to prevent SQL injection - did you try this already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can validate the columns being passed by checking that they are valid column names, e.g.

```
DECLARE @ColumnNames NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
    (
        SELECT  STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(c.name), ',')
        FROM    sys.columns AS c
        WHERE   object_id =  OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Foo', 'U')
        AND     EXISTS
                (   SELECT  1
                    FROM    STRING_SPLIT(@jsonField, ',') AS ss
                    WHERE   TRIM(ss.value) = c.name
                )
            );
```

This splits your string into the individual column names using [`STRING_SPLIT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), then uses this to filter the list of actual column names in the table (from [`sys.columns`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)), then rebuilds a single string using [`STRING_AGG()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Anything parsed that doesn't correlate to a valid column name, won't be used, and all columns names that do exist will be correctly escaped with [`QUOTENAME()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

You can then use this new variable in your dynamic statement, and be sure it only contains valid column names.

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT '+@ColumnNames +' FROM tblFoo';
```

**[Working Demo on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6c360/1)**

Comment: If it was an actual JSON array then you probably want `c.name IN (SELECT TRIM(value) FROM OPENJSON(@jsonField))` I'll admit OP doesn't actually have valid JSON in the example

Comment: I know you're not supposed to thank people in comments but thank you! You added functionality above and beyond what I was hoping for in your answer in checking the column names exist. And Charlieface is correct that I pseudocoded the json a bit, thanks for the suggested alteration